# set the font of UItextview

Tags: ios, uiview, fonts, uitextview

I have multiple textviews in my uiview I need to set the font size of this textviews, so I used the following code but it didn't change the font size,

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {

    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {

        ((UITextView *)subview).font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
    }

}
```

Comment: Add some log statements so you can narrow down where the problem is happening. At first glance this code looks OK, but if your text views are contained within other views then you won't see them. Log each subview under the for loop, then again after the if statement. Are you sure they are text views and not text fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jrturton says, perhaps your text views are subviews of a subview, then some kind of recursive code is needed. For example:

```
-(void) setNewFontToTextViews:(UIView*) theView {
    if([[theView subviews] count]) 
        for( UIView * subView in [theView subviews])
            [self setNewFontToTextViews:subView] ;
    else if([theView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
        [(UITextView*)theView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
}
```

Comment: thanks. you're right. I had I'll my elements in a scrollview that's why it didn't work, so I set the view to search in to my scrollview and it worked!